# More efficient way to write query

Tags: sql-server

I have two fields with an email address in #data table that I am trying to join on. I want it to join on rep email address and if that doesn't work, I want it to join on email. I tried running the following query:

```
select a.*
from #data a
join #email b on b.email=coalesce(a.rep_email_address,a.email) 
where a.rep_email_address<>a.email
```

This however doesn't work, because in the case where a.rep_email_adress is not null but doesn't match with b.email, it will drop the record instead of taking the a.email field.

This is the work-around I found:

```
select a.*
from #data a
join #email b on a.email=b.email
except 
select a.*
from #data a
join #email b on a.rep_email_address=b.email
union
select a.*
from #data a
join #email b on a.rep_email_address=b.email 
where a.rep_email_address<>a.email
```

This however, is far from optimal, so I am wondering- any way to write this to perform better/look cleaner or simpler? Just to clarify- this query works (the second query), I am wondering if there is a better way to write it.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to clarify if the problem is when the column is null or if it can be populated in both cases, and you want either for the join.

Comment: I stated that issue is not that a.rep_email_adress is null (it isn't)- but just doesn't match with b.email; however, a.email field does, so if rep_email_address didn't join (not because it is null but simply no join), I would like email field to join.

Comment: Well, yo said in the case, but that wasn't explicit that it could be and/or could not be null, but thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be much simpler. However, I also recommend you check the execution plan on this query to help you analyze if this is more optimal. [Or just compare the resulting execution times on your tables]

```
SELECT a.*
   FROM #data a
       JOIN #email b 
           ON (a.rep_email_address = b.email
               OR a.email = b.email )
WHERE a.rep_email_address<>a.email; 
# Not sure why or IF you need this where clause specifically.
```

Comment: Believe it or not, this causes duplication in the case where first rep_email_address matches, and then email matches. While my query doesn't

Comment: Would you mind sharing the expected output for these 3 cases - (i) where only rep_email_address matches b.email (ii) where only a.email matches b.email and (iii) where both a.rep_email_address and a.email are the same and they match b.email?

Comment: Add distinct to the select. You don't get duplicates in yours because you don't use union all @edost4

Comment: Also, if you just want to get rid of the duplicates from the resulting output, you could use the DISTINCT keyword immediately after SELECT. I recommend you do this only after you understand why the duplicates are generated in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    SomeColumn = ISNULL(e1.SomeColumn, e2.SomeColumn)
from 
    #data a
LEFT JOIN #email e1
    ON e1.email = a.rep_email_address
LEFT JOIN #email e2 
    ON e2.email = a.email
    AND e1.email IS NULL 
WHERE 
    a.rep_email_address <> a.email
    AND (
            e1.email IS NOT NULL
            OR 
            e2.email IS NOT NULL
        );
```

HTH, Jason

Answer (score 1):

SQL sever uses "[Three-Valued Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/handling-null-values)" in boolean evaluations:

- `NULL <> 2` --> Unknown (in your case in the where clause it will essentially become false)
- `NULL <> NULL` --> Unknown (same as above)
- `a <> b` --> true

In your case your original query should be:

```
select a.*
from #data a
join #email b on b.email=coalesce(a.rep_email_address,a.email) 
where ISNULL( a.rep_email_address, '' ) <> ISNULL( a.email, '' )
```

If you care about performance, then try to avoid the use of functions in join predicates or `WHERE` conditions as this prevents SQL Server from using indexes on columns that are passed into the function.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM #data AS a
    INNER JOIN #email AS b ON b.email = a.rep_email_address OR b.email = a.email
WHERE a.rep_email_address <> a.email OR ( a.rep_email_address IS NULL OR a.email IS NULL )
```

Summary:

Do not use `NULL`s to denote empty strings as this requires a lot of extra code to then check for `NULL`s

Comment: The result of this query is the same as of DeadLock's- ie. it duplicates some records. While my query doesn't

Comment: it means you have multiple matching records in #email table. As mentioned by @scsimon you cat try distinct